# Is it possible to set the concentric function in ipycytoscape?

Tags: ipycytoscape

In the concentric layout in cytoscape.js, it is possible to set which "layer" of the circle the nodes are in through the `concentric` variable of the layout:

```
  concentric: function( node ){ 
      return node.data("rank");
  }
```

Is there a similar function to this in ipycytoscape?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I already replied to your question on github, but this is a known issue, we need to implement a specific case for the concentric style. You can follow the issue here:https://github.com/cytoscape/ipycytoscape/issues/238
Thanks!